# Como empacotar um projeto Node.js em um executável?

Tags: javascript, node.js, grunt

Possuo um projeto Node.js porém preciso criar um executável para Windows e um para Linux, ambos contendo ainda o Node.js embutido.

Eu consegui fazer algo parecido numa aplicação `node-webkit` utilizando um *plugin* para o Grunt, porém gostaria de saber como fazer isso em uma aplicação Node.js normal.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/make-exe-files-from-node-js-app. Aparentemente existem algumas ferramentas para esse trabalho.

Comment: Acho que a melhor opção seria criar um programa usando elétron

Answer (score 16):

A solução é usar algo como [AppJS](http://appjs.com/). Ele cria um pacote que contem o seu aplicativo NodeJS assim como também o runtime (node.exe), as dependências, e ainda provê a possibilidade de usar uma biblioteca que permite criar GUIs usando HTML.

Comment: Acredito que o ruim de usar o AppJS é que vem com toda a GUI, caso não seja necessária uma. Aí acaba pesando bastante!

Comment: Exato, o que eu quero é criar um app de linha de comando.

Comment: Se não me engano basta não fazer uso de `app.createWindow(..)` que ele funciona igual que qualquer outro aplicativo NodeJS. Talvez seja até possível nem mesmo dar `require('appjs')` possibilitando usar apenar a parte de empacotamento do AppJS. O unico problema disso é que a biblioteca do Chromium vai junto com o aplicativo empacotado por mais que você não faça uso, o que deve aumentar o tamanho do mesmo, relativo a se não tivesse GUI.

Comment: Irei testar este modo que tu sugeriu e se der tudo certo confirmo a tua resposta. Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 12):

Atualmente parece não haver muitas opções para distribuir um binário *standalone* de uma aplicação Node.js.

Uma delas, e praticamente única, opção é o [nexe](https://github.com/crcn/nexe). Faz justamente o que você quer, mas existem alguns (grandes) problemas:

- Pode ser um pouco instável (seu código é bem simples).
- Não suporta módulos nativos.
- Não suporta Windows.

Apesar de todos os contras... vamos a um *hello world*:

1. Instalando o nexe:

```linux
 $ sudo npm install -g nexe
```

2. Criando um arquivo de teste:

```php
$ echo "console.log('Hello World');" > hello.js
```

3. Compilando a aplicação:

```linux
$ nexe -i hello.js -o hello
making application bundle with /home/talles/hello.js
writing application bundle:
[a partir daqui vêm uma saída 'pesada' do compilador]
```

`-i`, de *input*, são os arquivos de entrada; `-o`, de *output*, o arquivo de saída. Existe também `-t` de diretório temporário e `-r` de *runtime* (versão do node  a ser utilizada).

4. Pronto, o arquivo final está gerado:

```
$ ./hello
Hello World
```

No exemplo o arquivo final gerado teve um tamanho de 11Mb.

Comment: Não tão novo assim, olhei o histórico de commits. Tem poucos commits espalhados em mais de 2 anos de existência do projeto.

Comment: @gustavohenke verdade...